# Java ArrayList.add() overwrites whole list with last object

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm sorry if the question is unnecessary or if the problem is obvious, but I've tried to solve this for several hours and I'm running out of ideas.

```
public List<Letter> convertToList(char[] array){
  List<Letter> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    result.add(new Letter(array[i]));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here's the code of the Letter class:

```
public class Letter{
    private static char content; 
    private boolean guessed = false;
    public Letter(char content){
        this.content = content;
    }
    public char getContent(){
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

The result of running the covertToList() method is a List, which contains different Letter objects, which all have the same content. For example, if I pass in an array a = [T, E, S, T], the function will return a List with different Letter objects, which all have the content "T".
I found out that the list is overwritten in every step, so in the first iteration, the List is [T], in the second it's [E, E].

I feel kind of stupid for not seeing the issue. Can someone help?

Comment: `private static char content;` **remove** ***`static`***. That means one globally. Not per instance. `this.content` means you want one per instance.

Comment: BTW, your `Letter` looks similar to `Character`.

Comment: Yeah, I want to save some other properties in there, but I haven't mentioned them here for simplicity

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `content` field in the `Letter` class is defined `static`.
A **`static`** field **is common to all instances of a class**.

So when you create a new instance you are setting the common `content` field to all instances of that class.

You can simply remove the keyword `static` in front of the definition

```
public class Letter {
    // Removed the keyword static here
    private char content; 
    private boolean guessed = false;
    public Letter(char content){
        this.content = content;
    }
    public char getContent(){
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

You can find a complete official definition of the keyword static [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) where is stated:

> In this section, we discuss the use of the **static keyword** to **create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance** of the class.

Comment: Not sure, but it _might_ be because this is a common duplicate, and answering common duplicates is frowned upon.